# app.js code comparison because ejs not working

Tags: express, ejs

I'm using `express.js` and `ejs`.
I will post below two codes for the `app.js` file. The thing is that ejs and layout.ejs do not work with the one of those two codes, but it works perfectly with the other

Here are the two codes:

The first one, which ejs is working:

```
const express = require('express');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');

const path = require('path')
const app = express();
// Bodyparser
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));

/// EJS
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//PUBLIC FOLDER(css and js)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/public')));

// Express body parser
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/index.js'));
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users.js'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

and the second one, which ejs is not working:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path')

// Bodyparser
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));

//ROUTES
app.use('/', require('./routes/index'))
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users'))


// EJS
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('view options', { layout:'layout.ejs' });

//PUBLIC FOLDER(css and js)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/public')));


//DB CONFIG
const db = require('./config/keys').MongoURI;

// //Connect to mongo
mongoose.connect(db, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then( () => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
.catch( err => console.log(err));


app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server started on PORT ${PORT}`));
```

I'm trying to figure out what's the issue with the second code and doesn't make the ejs work. Can anyone have a quick glimpse and compare these two and tell me what's the problem? Thank you for your time

Comment: Are you getting any error message on `mongoose` connection?

Comment: Yeah i do. Good call, maybe that's what's causing the problem